# Changing the epoch to respective timezone in Highcharts and showing the time on x-axis

Tags: highcharts, timezone, handlebars.js, epoch, timezone-offset

I have some epoch timestamps in milliseconds that i am passing to the x-axis in highcharts. 
Now i have a select button which has some predefined timezones mentioned in it. For ex:  us-east, UK, Taiwan, Singapore etc.
So what i want is when a user selects a particular timezone, the timestamps on the graph should show the local time of that selected timezone.

For that i have written this sample code.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({      // This is for all plots, change Date axis to local time-zone
    global : {
    {{#if_eq tz "IST"}}
        useUTC : false
    {{/if_eq}}
    {{#if_eq tz "us-east"}}
        timezoneOffset: -5 * 60 
    {{/if_eq}}
    {{#if_eq tz "us-west"}}
        timezoneOffset: -7 * 60
    {{/if_eq}}
    {{#if_eq tz "uk"}}
        timezoneOffset: 1 * 60 
    {{/if_eq}}
    {{#if_eq tz "tw"}}
        timezoneOffset: 8 * 60  
    {{/if_eq}}
    {{#if_eq tz "sg"}}
        timezoneOffset: 8 * 60  
    {{/if_eq}}
    }
});
```

This code works if you select IST. The timestamps get converted to my local time.
But the time that i am getting when i select some other time zone on the chart is wrong. I don't know if i should convert the timezoneOffset in seconds and pass it or milliseconds or if i am doing it wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS:- I am using Handlebars for data passing, so don't get confused.
Thanks

Comment: Figured out the error. Basically i was putting the - sign wrong. Adding the offset wrongly. Getting the correct result now. :)

Comment: Your code is not safe for daylight saving time.  See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Also "epoch timestamps" is a misnomer. An epoch is a *fixed* value - and [there are several of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing).  You probably mean ["unix timestamps"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: @MattJohnson Yes i realized that it doesn't include daylight saving. Any idea how to include daylight saving time in highcharts?

Comment: Have you tried to set [UTC flag](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC) as false?

Comment: @SebastianBochan The UTC flag off means highcharts will convert the unix timestamp into the local time. Which is already happening. I was facing the problems where i was giving the timezoneOffset. Because i was giving the wrong sign. So changing of the sign solved the issue.

Comment: You are right, anyway thanks for feedback ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- You should use standardized [IANA time zone identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to identify each time zone.  For example, use `America/New_York`, not `us-east`.
- Don't attempt to determine the time zone offset for each zone manually, or you may easily have errors.
- Time zone offsets *change* over time.  This is due to both changes in standard time, and daylight saving time.
- The better way to do this in HighCharts is to hook the [`getTimezoneOffset`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.getTimezoneOffset) function.  This is a simple function that when passed the timestamp, returns the appropriate time zone offset.  You'll need to implement the function such that it returns the appropriate offset for the selected time zone at the correct time.
- The easiest way to do this is to integrate [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).  There is an example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/global/gettimezoneoffset/), which can also be found [in the HighCharts documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.getTimezoneOffset).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was a good insight. Used the moment-timezone library. I am getting the timezone times correctly. Hopefully it'll take care of DST too. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Yes, it does take care of DST.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Seems to be working fine. I am getting the time in the respective time-zones using moment-timezone. (thumbsup)